# can't change owner to partition table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i got  error when i run exec sp_changeobjectowner 'testtable','dbo'
'testtable' table
- Unable to modify table.
The object with name "testtable" already exists.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs if the user in context already owned the table object.

Follow [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275312)

Try using this syntax..

EXEC sp_changeobjectowner 'CurrentOwner.youTableName', 'dbo'